# I can't get the posts to be in the position I want

Tags: html, css, django

Im using django to create a website but I have limited knowledge about CSS and HTML , Im trying to create some new styling and posts in the page but somehow I could not manage to eliminate the blank which can be seen in picture.The posts are starting from bottom of the page no matter what I do. Im new at Django and CSS please instead of judging , guide me. Thank you!

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    {% load static %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EBOT Maintenance </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- Boxiocns CDN Link -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar close">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
      <span class="logo_name">EBOT</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
          <i class='bx bx-grid-alt' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">Anasayfa</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'home' %}">Anasayfa</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="{% url 'userSettings' %}">
            <i class='bx bx-collection' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Kullanıcı Ayarları</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'userSettings' %}">Kullanıcı Ayarları</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Kullanıcı Ekle</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'delete' %}">Kullanıcı Sil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Şifre Reset</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="{% url 'users' %}">
            <i class='bx bx-collection' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Kullanıcılar</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'users' %}">
            {% for user in users %}
            <div>
                <a href="">{{ user.username }}</a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="{% url 'parameters' %}">
            <i class='bx bx-book-alt' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Parametreler</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'parameters' %}">Parametreler</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'EbotManual' %}">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">EBOT Manual</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'EbotManual' %}">EBOT Manual</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'LedManual' %}">
          <i class='bx bx-plug' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">Led Manual</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'LedManual' %}">Led Manual</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="{% url 'TestRutins' %}">
            <i class='bx bx-cog' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Test Rutinleri</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="{% url 'TestRutins' %}">Test Rutinleri</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <!--
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-compass' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">Explore</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Explore</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-history'></i>
          <span class="link_name">History</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">History</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-cog' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">Setting</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu blank">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Setting</a></li>
        </ul>-->
      </li>
      <li>
    <div class="profile-details">
      <div class="profile-content"> 
      </div>
      <div class="name-job">
        <div class="profile_name">{{ user.username }}</div>
        <div class="job">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</div> <!--şuanda login type atalı değil halledilecek-->
      </div>
      <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class='bx bx-log-out' ></i></a>
      
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-content">
      <span class="text">EBOT Maintenance </span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
  let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
   let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;//selecting main parent of arrow
   arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
  console.log(sidebarBtn);
  sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
  });
  </script>

  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

```css
{% extends 'index.html' %}


{% block content %}

<style>
  .home-page{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }


</style>

<section class="home-section">
  <div class="home-container">
  <div class="home-page">
    <h2>
      EBOT Maintenance Hoş geldiniz.
    </h2>
      <p>lwrgkwrkgşlwrkgşl gwrlşkgşlwrkglşwr gkwrşlgkwrlş gkwrlşgkwr gkwrlşkg wşrkglwşrgk wrlkg şwrlgklşwrkglşwr kgşlwrkg wrkglşwr gkwrşlgkwr </p>
      İlerlemek için herhangi bir şeye tıklayın
    </div>
    </div>
    
</section>


{% endblock content %}
```

```html
/* Google Fonts Import Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: #11101d;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .logo-details i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name{
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links{
  overflow: visible;
}
.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover{
  background: #1d1b31;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: block
}
.sidebar .nav-links li i{
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu{
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sidebar .profile-details{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  background: none;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .profile-details img{
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details img{
  padding: 10px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details i,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .job{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 260px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.home-section .home-content{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu,
.home-section .home-content .text{
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu{
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-section .home-content .text{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width: 78px;
  }
  .sidebar.close{
    width: 0;
  }
  .home-section{
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRzTD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with `class="home-section"`, one in your `{% block content %}` and one in your `index.html`.  As this class has a vh of 100 the first will force the second to the bottom.